# Is there a method to determining how many books long your series needs to be?

Tags: plot, fantasy, world-building, series, plot-structure

I set out to write a trilogy, and feel my characters, world, and story are complex enough to warrant it. However, the more I dig into it, I’m sensing three books isn’t enough. But it will be a huge and complex undertaking to add a forth book since I’ll have to dive so deep into the intricacies of the universe I am developing.

I started teasing the idea of reducing it to a duology by stripping some of the complexity out. I can see how it would go, but feel like it’s a waste of the world I created (as in readers might be disappointed that I didn’t milk certain things). It would be way more manageable,though.

How do you decide whether to let a story be big by milking all it’s potential or to simplify it? Are there any methods to determine which is most effective to telling the story?

Also just a note, the complexities in my story aren’t just there for fun. They are necessary for the story to make sense. They just have a potential to be expounded on or left more “at a distance.”

Comment: What I observe is that the number of sequels correlates strongly to the number of copies sold ;-).

Comment: Important question: how did you decide it would/should be a trilogy? does your whole story can be separated in 3 different, independent stories with a greater, common "conflict"? did you just say "trilogies are cool!"?

Comment: @JoshPart Hi, I plotted it out, giving each book a separate 3AS that serves as an act in the overall story. I just felt the conclusion in book 3 wrapped up too soon, and there was untouched potential that would drive the themes home in a forth book. It definitely wasn’t a for-fun choice—it was a necessary one based on the depth of the story I have in my heart to tell.

Comment: Your agent will tell you, largely by ducking your calls

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I would first point out that beginning writers with no commercial success will approximately *never* sell a multi-book series.

The rule for a multiple-book story is relatively simple: The first book must absolutely stand alone. And every book must absolutely come to a conclusion that is satisfying even if it turns out to be the final book in the series.

That is not necessary true for commercially successful authors; Stephen King could likely publish a trilogy that doesn't meet these rules, because his reputation and following of paying customers ensures all costs will be recouped almost no matter what.

But if you look at the most successful series of all time, Harry Potter, JK Rowling was an unknown author, and the first book and following books very much stand alone. She does introduce more world elements as she goes along, that's fine.

That leads us to your epic, of 2 or 3 or 4 books.

How many independent novel length stories can you craft out of that?

What can you do in 100,000 words that can be an independent novel, with all the story arcs, following the Three Act Structure (3AS), and not leave the reader disappointed and wondering how the story ends?

The 3AS is recursive; the trilogy as a whole basically follows it (or a quadology?), The first book details a major problem, the 2nd (and maybe 3rd) develop complications, the final act resolves everything.

But each book must **also** follow that structure; Problem, Complications, Resolution.

At the end of the first book, the initial problem is solved, the world is introduced, but the bigger problem is just understood, not resolved.

At the end of the first star wars movie, the Death Star is destroyed but Darth Vader is not dead. In the second movie, Vader returns and the rebels are on the run. In the third, the rebels prevail.

You must do the same, each book must serve two purposes simultaneously: It must serve as an Act of the overall 3AS story, while simultaneously being a self-contained 3AS within its own 100,000 words.

That's how the business works.

Once you are successful, you may have more leeway. But even JK Rowling, the most financially successful author ever, wrote a series with each book having its own 3AS. Readers could be confident that buying the next book in the series, while developing their favorite characters further, would introduce a new problem, then complications, then have a satisfying resolution of the problem introduced.

So this is how your "how many books" question is resolved. It is not really about how much information and education you need to do. It is about how many independent, 100K word 3AS stories you can develop. If you have 400K words to write, you need 4 or 5 consecutive but independent 3AS books.

I'd suggest for the first one, you steal the approach used in Star Wars: The first film (we the audience see) acts as the "First Super Act" by introducing our hero, Luke Skywalker, and moving him from novice farmboy to Jedi Knight, an accomplished warrior. Also while introducing the world to the audience for the first time. (Edit: Also, Luke has firmly left behind the "farmboy normal world" where he began; as we'd expect from a First Act. He's a rebel soldier now.)

At the end of the first Super Act Luke is not a **master**, he's not ready to fight the big evil (Darth) directly, but Luke delivers on a key battle in a bigger war; he destroys the Death Star and puts Darth on his heels; spinning off into empty space. The Death Star is basically "the inciting incident" for the trilogy.

I imagine you need a similar transformation of your hero.

Comment: Indeed, the Death Star wasn't originally supposed to be destroyed in the first Star Wars movie; that was exactly what you say - tying things up somewhat in case the other movies don't get made. Just like, say, The Lord of the Rings was always meant to be a single book (with Tolkien pressured by his publisher to split it into three).

Comment: @Luaan: nitpick, LotR was always meant to be six books, and still is - you have Book One through Book Six, each with about a dozen chapters. Now indeed he was pressured to publish in three volumes - two books per volume - and title the volumes individually, but that's for practical reasons (as opposed to a single humongous volume, or six tiny volumes) and did not affect the writing. In fact each of the six books is 3AS, to some degree. LotR is often a poor example to use when discussing series since it is not, in fact, a series (and hence not a trilogy), but rather a single continuous story.

Comment: @amadeus thank you for your detailed answer! That is very helpful and gives me a lot to consider.

Comment: As a note, I have read a good web series which seems to follow 3AS (seems, because it's the middle of book 2 right now) not only in book structure, but even in individual chapters. This is more necessary for web series, because the chapters are posted periodically (usually one to three a week). If too many of them don't stand on their own, the readers will just stop reading.

Comment: That said, from my experience as a reader, 3AS can be a turn off if abused - having read some 15+ Andre Norton novels, her usage of it is just a bit too visible. Plus, she had an annoying habit of finishing the book immediately after resolution, leaving us, as readers, missing some closure. By immediately, I mean "hero killed the big bad, the end". We do not see the main character return home, or celebrate, or anything like that.

Comment: @jaskij That is just improper 3AS. The conclusion of 3AS should include the denouement; the final resolution of the plot, either a return to the Normal World, or the New Normal; if that is not possible. It is not long enough to be an Act, but good 3AS stories will end with a description of the world with the problem (for that book) and all its complications retired. The soldier comes home, or at least accepts his loss and new reality. The fight (for that book) is over.

Comment: `She does introduce more world elements as she goes along, that's fine` *as long as there is continuity, respect for the previous elements, and as little retcons as possible*. I agree with the point, I just wanted to expand it because it's quite easy to get "too excited" introducing new elements and forgot or not note that those new elements somehow "clash" with how the universe has been build up to that point, and that can make people really, really angry

Comment: @JoshPart Agreed; the other caveat: A new element cannot render some previously used element dumb, useless, or irrational. If in Book 1, everybody cowers at the threat of being magically chronobiased, Book 2 cannot introduce some cheap and easy protection against anybody chronobiasing you. The world elements have to be coherent, or harmonious, or whatever you want to call it. It is an incoherency in Star Trek; in one episode they program the transporter to filter out diseases. Seems like you'd do that every morning, like a shower, right? Any new cancer cells? Brain plaques? Unwelcome viruses?

Comment: @jaskij Then I'd argue that those books *didn't* have a resolution.  As a result they didn't follow the 3AS, and that's why they feel unsatisfying.

Comment: "Harry Potter, JK Rowling was an unknown author, and the first book and following books very much stand alone." The first book definitely. But from the 4th on there is more and more foreshadowing and even cliffhangers. They are still somewhat self-contained, but I doubt the series would be as popular if she stopped after book five. It was basically mid-story.

Comment: @Polygnome yes, people can fall in love with the continuing character growth, e.g. of Harry and the Gang. But each book is a 3AS, with a new main problem, complications, and main problem resolution. "Harry Potter and the XYZ": Although not advertised as such, each book is a mystery story, much like every new reboot of the Sherlock Holmes franchise. (Or lookalikes). But in all of those, the relationships between the super-detective, their medical sidekick, police allies and some Moriarty evolve incrementally as  episodes transpire, even though the mystery-du-jour is solved in 1 or two episodes.

Comment: @Amadeus For the first three books - yes. Especially the first book is extremely self-contained. If the series stopped after the first book, nobody would care about Voldemort.  And even in the second and third book this sis somewhat true. But the later books start to stage the greater story arc, which is not resolved until book seven. Yes, they still have an 3AS structure, and they do contain self-contained stories, but they introduce so much more background lore and foreshadow so many events that stopping mid book five or 6 would make you feel like you only got half the story.

Comment: @Polygnome I imagine that is because, given the success of the first three books, Rowling could do pretty much whatever TF she wanted and it would get published. She had a fan base that would buy a book called "Harry Potter Defecates in an Unusual Place". :-) My advice is for relatively unknown authors, I am not qualified to give advice to best-selling authors. The rules are different; both agents and publishers treat you much differently once there is proof you can write a blockbuster.